# max number of custom domains supported by per google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My project is to render different HTML content based on the traffic from different domains.

I wonder how many custom domains does the google app support?

and how many Google-managed SSL certificates does the google app support?
As I know google limit 20 managed certificates of subdomains per week for each base domain.

> If you are using subdomains, there is a limit of 20 managed certificates per week for each base domain. If you encounter the limit, App Engine keeps trying to issue managed certificates until all requests have been fulfilled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine does not have a limit for domains and subdomains. However as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl), you are limited to use only 20 managed SSL certificates per week within your domain. Additionally, please keep in mind the maintenance effort of each custom domain verification.

There is a [limit](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#ssl_certificates) of 100 multiple domains per Google-managed SSL certificate.