# Is F4_1G belong to the google app engine free Tier?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-appengine-node

Based on the GCP document  [Free Tier usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier-usage-limits)

App Engine has 28 hours per day of "F" Instancees.

I wonder does F4_1G type also belong to the free tier of 28 hours per day?

F1 and F4_1G is so different [Instance classes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer your question, yes F4_1G is also under the free tier offered by Google Cloud Platform. The only difference of the F4_1G to the F1 is in terms of the amount of memory and CPU available to each instance, hence the cost. Here's an example:

F1 would cost $0.05 per hour per instance, while the F4_1G would cost $0.30 (based on the Iowa (us-central1) location). Check this pricing [list](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) to know the cost per region.

Therefore, when using F4_1G, you're using x6 of the usual default instance hours. In conclusion, you'll use "24 instance hours" if you run an F4_1G non-stop for 4 hours.

Comment: Thanks, RJC. It is very helpful. Could you please also help me to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68621852/max-number-of-custom-domains-supported-by-per-google-app-engine

Comment: Is there a reliable source that would explain this statement that free hours should be divided by price ratio of X/f1 for X instance_class?

Comment: @Shrike the best I could find is [only a hint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/quotas#Instances) at this: "When you view your bill, you will not see the names of the individual instance classes ... The bill will apply the appropriate multiple of instance hours for each instance class you use. For example, if you use an F4 instance for one hour, you see "Frontend Instance" billing for four instance hours at the F1 rate. "